# Can't start tomcat with bat file in windows

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat

I have unzipped `apache-tomcat-8.0.28` successfuly.Then I tried to start tomcat using cmd with `startup.bat`.But it returns below and tomcat isn't started.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

What should I do ?

Comment: output seems normal to me. have you looked at the logs?

Comment: log isn't got pop up.

Comment: Check the logs at D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\logs\catalina.out

Comment: catalina.out file is empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`startup.bat` typically opens a new command line. If the new command line closes immediately, it's hard to recognize the error message that's displayed for fractions of a second.

You can check error messages in tomcat's log/catalina.out or see them interactively by using `catalina.bat run` - this will not open a new window and not go to the background - instead start tomcat in the current command line window, displaying all the log information. It should be easy to spot the problem this way.